# What is the minimum `metadata` specification for the Open Data Cube?

Tags: python, metadata, satellite, open-data-cube

There is a [standard metadata definition here](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/blob/develop/datacube/index/default-metadata-types.yaml), but I would like to create a new one, with only the absolutely required fields.

What is the minimum set of values that can be used to define a metadata type in the Open Data Cube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good example in documentation https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ops/dataset_documents.html explaining which is `required` and which is `optional` to create a `dataset` yaml file.